# For which $\alpha, \beta$ the series converges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}}$?

Tags: power-series

I don't know wheteher I determine convergence properly, because it seems for me thath I have a problem in the end.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}}$$

I want to assume the asymptotic similarity with $\sum\frac{1}{n^{\delta}}$, which is convergent for $\delta>1$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{(n+1)^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}}-\frac{n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}})\\\frac{\beta}{\alpha}<1\Rightarrow \beta<\alpha$$

Additionally:
$$(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}<n^{\alpha}$$
$$ f(n) =(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}-n^{\alpha}  $$
Setting to $0$ and dividing by $n^{\beta}$:

$$ \frac{n+1}{n}^{\beta}-1-n^{\alpha-\beta}=0 \\ (\frac{n+1}{n})^{\beta}-n^{\alpha-\beta}=1 / \ln(\cdot) \\ \beta\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-(\alpha-\beta)\ln(n) = 0 \\ \beta=\alpha\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}$$

I don't know, whether the answer is $\alpha>1$ and $\beta=\alpha\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}$ or whether I'm wrong

EDIT
I used the derivative for the f(x) and got:
$$\beta(n+1)^{\beta-1}-\beta n^{\beta-1}-\alpha n^{\alpha-1}=0 \\1+\frac{1}{n}-1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}n^{\alpha-\beta-1+1}=0\\ \frac{1}{n}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}n^{\alpha-\beta}\\ \alpha-\beta<0$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a cleaner proof of convergence for this almost-telescoping series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012000/is-there-a-cleaner-proof-of-convergence-for-this-almost-telescoping-series)

Answer (score 2):

$$(n+1)^{\beta}=n^{\beta}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^\beta=n^{\beta } \left(1+\frac{\beta }{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
$$(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}=n^{\beta } \left(\frac{\beta }{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}}\sim \beta n^{\beta-\alpha-1}$$

Comment: Nice, however, I can't see, for which $\alpha, \beta$ it converges

Answer (score 0):

We can use that

$$(n+1)^{\beta}=n^{\beta}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^\beta=n^\beta+\beta \frac1{n^{1-\beta}}+\frac{\beta (\beta-1)}2\frac1{n^{2-\beta}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3-\beta}}\right)$$

and therefore

$$\frac{(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha}}=\beta \frac1{n^{1+\alpha-\beta}}+\frac{\beta (\beta-1)}2\frac1{n^{2+\alpha-\beta}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3+\alpha-\beta}}\right)$$